# Reading json from remote HTML/json item in iOS app

Tags: html, ios, json, wordpress, afnetworking

I have a server which I don't own, I can only upload an HTML file or .json file.

In my app I use AFNetwerking's AFJSONRequestOperation to handle json requests.

When i try to just paste my json object in an html file and upload it,I go the the address of the html file but the server automatically parses the response as a string and puts backslashes and all kind of junk in the mix which makes AFNetworking fail to parse the json.

How can I write the html file to just get the json untouched or knows to parse it as application/json?

Comment: I will just edit that the website is made using webpress if that spawns more options to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, As long as you enter the line `[AFJSONRequestOperation addAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"]];`
AFNetworking can handle the data even when parsed as Text/html.
That solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to upload the file using the .json extension. If you save it as .html the server probably will send the headers as "text/html".

Also, if you have non-ASCII characters (like áñßø...) you have to escape these chars. For example: "José" must be encoded as "Jos\u00e9".

Also, if you have quotes and double quotes, you must escape them too with backslashes.

Comment: do you mean even the " that i use to mark that the variable con taints a string? for example {food : "pizza"}

Comment: You have to put " also in "food", like this `{"food" : "pizza"}`.

Comment: You can check your JSON data on this website: [http://json.parser.online.fr](http://json.parser.online.fr)